# How to generate and store the "initial" state of an existing database in Liquibase DATABASECHANGELOG table?

Tags: liquibase

I'm in the process of integrating the springboot microservices with Liquibase. Prior to executing any changesets, I would like extract the "initial" state of an existing database(Oracle) and store in Liquibase DATABASECHANGELOG table. Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you would do is use the `diffChangeLog` command to generate a changelog.xml that contains all the changes needed to update a pristine database to the existing state of your database. If you already have a changelog, this would append to the end of that changelog, and you might want to manually rearrange the changesets so they are in the correct order.

You then use the `changeLogSync` command to populate the existing database with a DATABASECHANGELOG table that shows all of those changes have been deployed to that database.